# Dummy regression - p-value interpretation

Tags: regression, p-value, linear

Suppose I want to predict the quality of an essay as a function of how many essays a person produces in a year. Something like this:

$quality = m_{0}\ (quantity/year) + k$

in which, $m_0$ is the angular coefficient and $k$ the linear one.

As a way to refine my results, I am including a dummy variable for each person in the data set. This way the information regarding an individual's trajectory is used. And this is something I want, since I want to find out the individual's behavior. The equation turns out to be something like this:

$quality = m_{0}\ (quantity/year) + k + d_1 m_1+d_2 m_2+...$

$d_1$ is a dummy variable associated with person 1, $d_2$ with person 2 and so on.

My data set is divided among $n$ themes, so that I do $n$ linear regressions, one for each theme. My final goal is to analyze the $m_0$s.

The result is: a lot of p-values for $m_0$ that are bigger than 0.05. But for the same $m_0$, I get F p-values $< 0.05$ (from F-test). These should tell me that among those variables there is one that can explain the change in $quality$. Am I wrong?

Should I discard the ones with p-value $>0.05$ even though the F p-value aren't or consider them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you get a significant effect of m0 if you fit a single model to the whole data set, ignoring the theme. But if you fit a seperate model to each subset (corresponding to a theme), you get lot of themes that have no significant effect of m0.

So it could be that m0 really has effect only in some themes. Or it could be that the study is underpowered to detect the effect in individual themes, especially rare themes.

To see if there is a substantial difference in the m0 effect in different themes, you could fit a mixed effect model with a random intercept and a random m0 effect, both with theme as grouping variable. In R this would be
lme(quality ~ (m0|theme))

It is generally bad practice to filter on p-values.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Let me see if I get it right. By doing as you suggested I would fit the entire dataset, but this time without considering the effect of the individuals and adding a dummy for each theme?

Comment: What would be the variable to analyze in these case? (Considering it's not the p-value)

Comment: Do each author have only one theme? In that case, authors are nested within themes so you could write lme(quality~(m0|theme) + (1|author/theme)). This would give you an m0 effect for each theme as well as a random intercept for each author. In any case, the inference you are interested in is the fixed and random effect of m0. For example, if the fixed effect is -2 and the random effect has an SD of 1, it would mean that 97.5% of themes have a negative association between m0 and quality, since a random variable with mean (-2) and SD=1 had 2.5% chance of being positive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I'll try to implement it